# Run npm script with nodemon command

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

I am testing GraphQL Server from Apollo and what to integrate nodemon to it. Here's sample file structure :

```
build/
src/
server.js
```

Here my npm scripts looks like this

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "babel --presets es2015,stage-2 server.js -d build/  &&  node build/server.js",
   "dev": "nodemon server.js" // Sample code here
}
```

What `npm run start` would do is to convert ES6 code into `build/server.js` using babel and execute it. This would start the server correctly.

What I want is to watch for changes in `server.js` or in `src/` and restart the server if changes occur. Here I want to execute `npm run start` command if any changes occur. What is the correct 'nodemon' command to my need. Its better if I could use `npm run dev` like command to start development using nodemon.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [gulpjs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) to watch any changes in specific folders and then command it to do something.
With your sample, you want to convert the code to es6 too. so it also need [gulp-bable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel) and . you can include [babel-preset-stage-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-stage-2) if you want. So you can simply put the code below in gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('build-es2015', () => {
    return gulp.src('server.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
gulp.task('watch', () => {
    gulp.watch(['./app/*.js'], ['build-es2015'])
})
```

Basically, the task 'watch' will keep watching the specific files. When they are saved then it will to execute the task 'build-es2015' to convert to es6.

And then nodemon, it needs [gulp-nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nodemon) then you can do on gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('server', () => {
  nodemon({
    script: 'build/server.js',
    ext: 'js',
    ignore: [
      'server.js',
      'node_modules/**',
      'test/**',
      'build/**'
    ]
  })
  .on('restart', () => { console.log(`Server restarted!`) })
})
```

The above will keep watching build/server.js'. whenever it is changed, nodemon will automatically restart the server.

And the last piece for gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('dev', ['server', 'watch'])
```

Include the tasks that need to be executed for gulp command.

```
$ gulp dev
```

or with npm command

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "gulp dev"
}
```

so you can `npm run start` as well.

And dont forget to require all packages in gulpfile.js

```
const gulp       = require('gulp')
const babel      = require('gulp-babel')
const nodemon    = require('gulp-nodemon')
```